# A total order of rectangles related to containment

Tags: reference-request, computational-geometry, order-theory, ordering

Suppose you have a set of rectangles $R_1,\dots,R_n$ in the plane, each described by an upper left point $p_1 \in \mathbb R^2$ and a lower right point $p_2 \in \mathbb R^2$, all pairwise different.

You are set the task to paint them in a certain order (shuffled from $1,\dots,n$) so that a rectangle never gets totally overpainted by another one.

To my slight astonishment I found out, that this can be done by introducing a total order on the space of rectangles so that $R_x < R_y$ implies that $R_y$ does not contain $R_x$.

The order is defined as follows. Let $$R_1 = \bigl((x_{11},y_{11}),(x_{12},y_{12})\bigr), R_2 = \bigl((x_{21},y_{21}),(x_{22},y_{22})\bigr). $$ Then $R_1 < R_2$ if one of the following conditions holds:

- $x_{11} < x_{21}$.
- $x_{11} = x_{21}$ and $y_{11} > y_{21}$.
- $(x_{11},y_{11}) = (x_{21},y_{21})$ and $x_{12} > x_{22}$.
- $(x_{11},y_{11},x_{12}) = (x_{21},y_{21},x_{22})$ and $y_{12} < y_{22}$.

I am certain that this order must be well-known, but I could not find a reference for it. Do you know a reference?

---

Here is a C# implementation of the order:

```
/// <summary>
/// Compares rectangles <paramref name="r1"/> and <paramref name="r2"/>.
/// If <paramref name="r1"/> is less than <paramref name="r2"/> then
/// <paramref name="r2"/> can not contain <paramref name="r1"/>.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="r1">The first rectangle.</param>
/// <param name="r2">The second rectangle.</param>
/// <returns>-1 iff r1 is less than r2, +1 iff r2 is less than r1, 
/// 0 iff r1 equals r2</returns>
private int LessRect(Rect r1, Rect r2)
{
    System.Windows.Point p11 = r1.BottomLeft;
    System.Windows.Point p12 = r1.TopRight;

    System.Windows.Point p21 = r2.BottomLeft;
    System.Windows.Point p22 = r2.TopRight;

    // First sort by the upper left corner (== BottomLeft).

    // First by X.

    if (p11.X < p21.X)
    {
        // I start more left, so I stay below.
        return -1;
    }

    if (p11.X > p21.X)
    {
        // I start more right, so I am on top.
        return +1;
    }

    Debug.Assert(p11.X == p21.X);

    // Then by Y.

    if (p11.Y > p21.Y)
    {
        // I am higher by Y so I can afford to be below.
        return -1;
    }

    if (p11.Y < p21.Y)
    {
        // I am lower by Y so I must be on the top.
        return +1;
    }

    Debug.Assert(p11 == p21);

    // Now upper left corners coincide.
    // Sort by lower right corners ( == TopRight ).

    // First sort by X.

    if (p12.X < p22.X)
    {
        // My opponent can occlude me total, so I must be on top.
        return +1;
    }

    if (p12.X > p22.X)
    {
        // My opponent has no chance to occlude me total, so I can stay below.
        return -1;
     }

     Debug.Assert(p12.X == p22.X);

     // Now X is equal: sort by Y.

     if (p12.Y < p22.Y)
     {
         // My opponent can not occlude me total, so I can stay below.
         return -1;
     }

     if (p12.Y > p22.Y)
     {
         // My opponent does occlude me total, so I must be on top.
         return +1;
     }

     // Now x and y are equal and taking
     // all together:
     // upper left corners coincide
     // lower right corners coincide
     // so Rectangles are identical

     Debug.Assert(p12.Y == p22.Y);
     Debug.Assert(p12 == p22);

     Debug.Assert(r1 == r2);

     // The ordering is a total-ordering because it
     // is a product ordering of total-orderings for all coordinates.

     return 0;
}
```

Comment: Many readers of this site would actually prefer an "abstract description" over a rather verbose piece of code.

Comment: Your ordering is lexicographic order with respect to the mapping $((x_1,y_1),(x_2,y_2)) \mapsto (x_1,-y_1,-x_2,y_2)$.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus Thanks for taking your time to edit my question! Of course you are right that my ordering is a variant of lexicographic, but I wanted to stress more the "semantic" aspect of the ordering, namely that Rx < Ry implies Ry can not occlude Rx, so that it expresses a "spatial relation" related to the rectangle areas. I thought that exactly this spatial relation might have led others to have discovered this ordering already in the context of computational geometry or graphics processing. I posted the full code because its comments should make clear that the spatial relation is satisfied.

Comment: @JürgenBöhm This total order is an intriguing observation. Here is one minor suggestion. "$R_x < R_y$ implies that $R_y$ does not contain $R_x$." The direction of order seem counterintuitive since "<" is usually associated with "smaller than". It should be more nature to let $R_x < R_y$ imply that $R_x$ does not contain $R_y$, that is, $R_x$ cannot be "bigger than" $R_y$.

Comment: @HEKTO, Please check Yuval's comment above. It is a total order.

Comment: @HEKTO, you are right that "does not contain"-ness is not transitive. However, the total order in the question does NOT characterize "does not contain"-ness. It only implies "does not contain". You may want to read the question more carefully. (On the other hand, it would have been clearer had OP clarified that this total order does not characterize "does not contain"-ness).

Comment: A minor lesson: when Yuval says something that is not right, take a deep breath and think for another day.